# One div won't center

Tags: html, css

I can't get my block div's to center except my text on top and bottom. For some reason they are aligning only to the left.

I've tried margin:auto and setting the width 100%. I'm sure its probably an easy fix but I can't seem to find the error in my code.

Only thing that fixes it is adding a margin-left, however it doesn't look in all dimensions so would prefer if it naturally centered as it should.

http://jsfiddle.net/cV4UJ/

Some HTML please see JSfiddle instead:

```
                                <!-- Blocks -->
                                <div class="grid_24 center">
                                        <div class="grid_7">
                                                <div class="grey_boxes">
                                                    <p class="grey">
                                                    test
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="complete">
                                                        Complete 
                                                        <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/gmktg/dub-img/newbie_be_icon_complete.png" class="complete" alt=" "/>
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="grid_1">
                                            <p>

                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="grid_7">
                                            <div class="panel">
                                                <div class="boxes card">
                                                    <p class="boxtext">
                                                    test
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="rotate">
                                                        <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/gmktg/dub-img/newbie_be_icon_rotate.png" class="rotate" alt=" "/>
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="boxesback card">
                                                    <p class="boxtext">
```

test

button

```
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="grid_7">
                                            <div class="panel">
                                                <div class="boxes card">
                                                    <p class="boxtext">
                                                        test
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="rotate">
                                                        <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/gmktg/dub-img/newbie_be_icon_rotate.png" class="rotate" alt=" "/>
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="boxesback card">
                                                    <p class="boxtext">
```

test

button

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: to center a div relative to its parent, you need:a div with specified width, with a width smaller than its parent and with css property margin: 0 auto;

Comment: if the div has only text, you could set div width to 100% and text-align:center

Comment: you do not specify which div you want to align

Comment: I would like to align the block cards to the center as they are floating to the left at the moment

Comment: i assume you talk about the div.grid_24.center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/cV4UJ/2/

to make it work, you need to force the `div.center` to behave like a div (right now it has the properties of `.grid_24` class, which is an inline left floated element)

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    float: none !important;
    display: block !important;
    width: 980px;
    clear: both;
}
```

the most important properties needed for a centered div:

- margin: 0 auto;
- no float
- be a block element (original display for a div)
- have a width

i also put !important, to force it lose all the properties of grid_24

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. It's still aligning to the left though :/